# Crittercism Reports Crashing on main.m

Tags: ios, crash, program-entry-point, crittercism

**Short Description**:
We have a SIGABRT crash from the main.m. The only information we get is a minimal crash report from Crittercism and we have no idea how to reproduce the crash.

**Detailed Description**:
In addition to above. Our initial theory was that users were getting crashes from core data processes but there is no mention of this in the stack trace. We thought that when users try to run the app again, it simply can't load due to damaged data. We don't kick off any code of ours, so how can we crash at such an really stage. We have had this problem for a few different app versions with no particular libraries added or removed so it should not be due to any corrupted files.

We're not sure if there is any clear answer here as the question is quite complicated with the information we have but if anyone at least could advise **any leads to investigate and analyse** - that would be great.

```
Crashed Thread

libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fb350 __pthread_kill + 8 + 8    
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35ada973 abort + 95 + 94    
libc++abi.dylib 0x3307cd4f abort_message + 75 + 74  
libc++abi.dylib 0x33079ff9 _ZL17default_terminatev + 25 + 24    
libobjc.A.dylib 0x326c9a77 _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 147 + 146    
libc++abi.dylib 0x3307a07b _ZL19safe_handler_callerPFvvE + 79 + 78  
libc++abi.dylib 0x3307a114 _ZSt9terminatev + 20 + 19    
libc++abi.dylib 0x3307b599 __cxa_current_exception_type + 1 
libobjc.A.dylib 0x326c99d1 objc_exception_rethrow + 13 + 12 
CoreFoundation 0x38328f21 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 457 + 456  
CoreFoundation 0x38328d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105 + 104    
UIKit 0x39af947d -[UIApplication _run] + 669 + 668  
UIKit 0x39af62f9 UIApplicationMain + 1121 + 1120    
DM 0x0010e41b main (main.m:14)
```

Rest of Threads (could be useful for more information)

```
Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387eb648 kevent64 + 24 + 24    
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a048658 _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 36 + 35

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fbd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8 + 8
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a75a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366 + 365

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fbd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8 + 8
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a75a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366 + 365

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387eaeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 + 20
CoreFoundation 0x383b7045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129 + 128
CoreFoundation 0x383b5da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883 + 882
CoreFoundation 0x38328ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357 + 356
CoreFoundation 0x38328d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105 + 104
WebCore 0x3a3a9a45 _ZL12RunWebThreadPv + 445 + 444  
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a80311 _pthread_start + 309 + 308

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387eaeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 + 20
CoreFoundation 0x383b7045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129 + 128
CoreFoundation 0x383b5da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883 + 882
CoreFoundation 0x38328ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357 + 356
CoreFoundation 0x38328d49 CFRunLoopRunInMode + 105 + 104
Foundation 0x327edbcd +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 309 + 308
Foundation 0x3287167d __NSThread__main__ + 973 + 972
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a80311 _pthread_start + 309 + 308

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387eaf1c semaphore_timedwait_trap + 8 + 8
CoreLocation 0x33ff06e9 _Z22CLClientInvokeCallbackP10__CLClient13CLClientEventP11objc_object + 345 + 344
CoreLocation 0x33ff3d4d ___CLClientCreateConnection_block_invoke_0 + 389 + 388
CoreLocation 0x3402a073 __setEventHandler_block_invoke_0 + 347 + 346
libxpc.dylib 0x33f557e9 _xpc_connection_mach_event + 773 + 772
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a049529 _dispatch_mach_msg_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 125 + 124
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a045e91 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 81 + 80
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a0497b7 _dispatch_mach_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 163 + 162
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a045e91 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 81 + 80
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a045dc1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 41 + 40
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a045e91 _dispatch_queue_drain$VARIANT$mp + 81 + 80
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a045dc1 _dispatch_queue_invoke$VARIANT$mp + 41 + 40
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a04691d _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 185 + 184
libdispatch.dylib 0x3a046ac1 _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 85 + 84
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a75a11 _pthread_wqthread + 361 + 360

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fbd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8 + 8
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a75a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366 + 365


Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387eaeb4 mach_msg_trap + 20 + 20
CoreFoundation 0x383b7045 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 129 + 128
CoreFoundation 0x383b5da3 __CFRunLoopRun + 883 + 882
CoreFoundation 0x38328ebd CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 357 + 356
CoreFoundation 0x383879bb CFRunLoopRun + 99 + 98
DM 0x0024f947 +[ASIHTTPRequest runRequests] + 151
Foundation 0x3287167d __NSThread__main__ + 973 + 972    
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a80311 _pthread_start + 309 + 308

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fb594 select$DARWIN_EXTSN + 20 + 20
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a80311 _pthread_start + 309 + 308

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fbd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8 + 8
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a75a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366 + 365

Thread: Unknown Name
libsystem_kernel.dylib 0x387fbd98 __workq_kernreturn + 8 + 8
libsystem_c.dylib 0x35a75a16 _pthread_wqthread + 366 + 365
```

Thank you very much for your time - we appreciate it allot.

Thanks,
Justas

Comment: Have you tried installing a custom exception handler?

Comment: @trojanfoe: the SDK being used by Justas is catching the exceptions already. Please, don't use your own custom exception handlers ever. This will do more harm than good and it is everything but not easy to do right (even if it looks simple at first sight). Here is blog post that shows some of the reasons why: http://landonf.bikemonkey.org/code/crashreporting/Reliable_Crash_Reporting_1.1.20130119.html

Comment: @Kerni I disagree; I haven't had a problem with it and use my exception handler to dump the stack frames into my own log file, which my apps use.

Answer (score 2):

The crash happens because of an exception, see `objc_exception_rethrow` in the stack trace of the crashed thread, which is the main thread. Sadly the `Exception Backtrace` and `Exception Reason` are not available. Without that you cannot do anything. That would show you where in your code the exception was raised and what the actual exception was about.

Exceptions get rethrown by the runtime into another runloop, to catch them the crash reporting framework would be required to support this. Crittercism is using PLCrashReporter under the hood, which does support this. But maybe either you have an old version of the SDK installed or they are using an old version of it.

Comment: yes we're using latest version of the SDK. And we have proper reports for most of crashes. Thank you.

Comment: Do any of the crash reports you have contain an exception reason or `Last Exception Backtrace`? If not, I would suggest to contact Crittercism if they support this. And if so, how to set it up und use it. Because for such crashes there is no other way to get the information you need to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

@Kerni, Thank you for your time!

We have contacted Crittercism and they hava advised us to look into breadcrumbs - this would allow us to put number of custom calls all around the app (where user is triggering any particular action + other important system calls) and once it app will crash Crittercism will store 99 last breadcrumbs for us. This will allow us to understand what was user's journey to this particular crash.

Also we came across ability of using metadata to contact users directly and to comunicate with them. This could also allow us to get more information on a particular issue. And most important it will allow us to react to crashes more efficiently.

I understand this is not a proper answer for our issue, but at least we will have all required tools to get the answer after implementation.

Thanks

Comment: And why don't they provide a `Last Exception Backtrace` which would give you the details without all that hassle?

Comment: It looks like it's due to type of problem we have in this particular issue. Usually we get Last Exception Backtrace with no problem, but here app crashes in a way it's not available for us. Does it make sense?

Comment: Actually no, this does not make sense. This is a crashed caused by an exception. And when there is an exception, there is a `Last Exception Backtrace` and a string showing the exception reason. I don't know of any scenario where this could be missing.